# Strange behavior in Spring3 JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

Hi Friends
I am getting this exception in my envt. and it is not fix when it will cause. I am using Spring 3, JPA and Hibernate and we use the EntityManager provided by server and the transaction is also provided by server. But the method which throws this exception does not annotated with @Transaction and no transaction is used. See the exception below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
2011-04-27 13:10:56,141 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.nextTimestamp(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:85)
2011-04-27 13:10:56,141 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:573)
2011-04-27 13:10:56,141 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.getRawSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:87)
2011-04-27 13:10:56,141 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.getSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:67)
2011-04-27 13:10:56,141 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:436)
2011-04-27 13:10:56,151 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:82)
2011-04-27 13:10:56,151 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:61)
2011-04-27 13:10:56,151 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:39)
2011-04-27 13:10:56,151 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:34)
2011-04-27 13:10:56,151 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.jpa.injection.InjectedEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(InjectedEntityManagerFactory.java:82)
2011-04-27 13:10:56,177 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:234)
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Persistence deployment descriptor for dev profile -->
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">


     <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
        <jta-data-source>java:/myDatasource</jta-data-source> 
        <!--Here I have my list of entity beans -->
         <properties> 
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
              <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="persistence-units/myPU"/>

        </properties>
     </persistence-unit>  


</persistence>
```

Spring configuration

```
<context:annotation-config /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.name" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>  
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence-units/myPU"/>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
 <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
      <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager"/>
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="UserTransaction"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: See the updated original post for persistence.xml

Comment: hmmm. and nothing about caches?

Comment: Yes, we dont use any cache and still see this exception. And I can not reproduce this issue on demand. Same code sometimes works fine and suddenly it start throwing this exception

Comment: Please show your Spring context (at least the part where you specify the persistence context

Comment: See the original post for spring config which I just updated

Comment: Check my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773389/product-creation-doesnt-work-under-spring-mvc-with-jpa/12934398#12934398

Comment: Did anyone found the answer to this?